# How can I follow a windows shortcut in power shell?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, powershell

I am using powershell and I have a shortcut to my destination directory in the current directory. I want to change the current directory to the one pointed to by the shortcut. Logically what I want to do is:

```
cd your-files-here.lnk
```

and wind up where over that points. What I get instead is:

```
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'your-files-here.lnk' because it does not exist.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\pscx\Modules\CD\Pscx.CD.psm1:111 char:17
+                 Set-Location <<<<  $path -UseTransaction:$UseTransaction
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (your-files-here.lnk:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I tried

```
ii your-files-here.lnk
```

But this opens an explorer window instead of changing the current directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may add this to your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file.  The `cd` command will then work as desired.

```
remove-item alias:cd -force
function cd($target)
{
    if($target.EndsWith(".lnk"))
    {
        $sh = new-object -com wscript.shell
        $fullpath = resolve-path $target
        $targetpath = $sh.CreateShortcut($fullpath).TargetPath
        set-location $targetpath
    }
    else {
        set-location $target
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change "$fullpath = resolve-path $target" to "$fullpath = (resolve-path $target).Path" to get it to work.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that PowerShell auto-complete doesn't work for non-directories after I type "cd ", which means I have to type the whole name of the .lnk file myself.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, Windows does not make it easy to work with shortcuts. This should work:

```
$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
cd $sh.CreateShortcut('your-files-here.lnk').TargetPath
```

Comment: This works where the target is a conventional local path, but in at least one case, the shortcut is pointing to a UNC path. In this case, TargetPath is empty.

Comment: That is odd, I have .lnk shortcuts to UNC paths and the .Targetpath property has the path in it. I even tried taking one and making the targetpath empty and it wouldn't save that way.

Comment: Never mind. I was doing something else wrong. Works fine.

Comment: You should tell us what was wrong so future generations can benefit!

Comment: In short: CreateShortcut wants an absolute path.

Comment: `cd $sh.CreateShortCut( (Resolve-Path 'your.lnk').ProviderPath ).TargetPath` # should resolve a network one too.

Answer (score 4):

Is the shortcut a necessity?

You could use a Windows link for this.  See `mklink /?` for more information on Windows links/junction points.

Comment: I am not the one who decided on shortcuts.

Comment: This answer was tremendously helpful to me and the solution worked smoothly, event if it technically doesn't solve the (shortcut) problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but there is a module you can add to powershell that helps with quicker navigation - called "z".

Here is more info:  https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SpendLessTimeCDingAroundDirectoriesWithThePowerShellZShortcut.aspx